# Form Inputs and PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Need a little help with my coding. I'm working on a project in which it will accept 5 different numbers and insert them into a PHP array. The codes I have tried are written below. Both of them would make all the 5 contents of my array the same number, appreciate a little help please? Never dealt with array in PHP yet.

```
<form action="activity_1.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="number">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

So far these are the ones I've tried:

```
$no = array();

for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    array_push($no, $_POST['number']);
}
```

Also

```
$no = array();

for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    //$no[$i]= $_POST['number'];
}
```

Comment: So you want a form with 5 number inputs?

Comment: What are different numbers that you are entering in text box?

Comment: You have only one number input in your form, so you only send one number, not five. In the loops you are getting the same (and unique) sent number for each iteration. So, you need to put more number inputs in your form, or you need to send your form multiple times. Study a bit more, please ;)

Comment: Seems the question is unrelated to JS ?

Comment: "*it will accept 5 different numbers*" - your form only has one number input?

Comment: Hello. Well, this is a school requirement of mine in a course in college. I've just started studying JavaScript and PHP since we have just begun studying about these languages. This is the professor's requirement btw to have only one input, I know that it seems weird but he said to make it put all the numbers inside an array. 

In regards to the JS part, I think I made a mistake, I was going to ask a question about JS a week a ago but fixed the problem myself so I cancelled it. I think Stackoverflow drafted it and I ended up just clearing the form, I think I left some parts of it?

Comment: I think what he meant is that one number would be inserted on every submit by using the same input field. For example, type in 20, click submit and it would insert it to array[0], then type in another number it loops around.

Comment: did u see (and try) my answer ?

Comment: Yes I did, I am trying it right now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may use one session variable to store the posted data.

So slightly amend your code into the following :

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<form action="#" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="number">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>



<?php
    if ( !isset($_SESSION["no"]) ) {
    $_SESSION["no"]=array();
    }

if (isset($_POST["number"])){
array_push($_SESSION["no"], $_POST['number']);
}



for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
    if (isset($_SESSION["no"][$i])) {
       if ($_SESSION["no"][$i]!="") {
         echo " Number you entered was: " .$_SESSION["no"][$i] . "<br>";
        }
    }
}


?>
```

In my opinion the code can be further amended so that

a) you should have a button to "clear" all the previous entered number;

b) I don't know whether it is necessary, but you may wish to add a function to check whether a newly entered number is the same as one of the past numbers entered, and if they are the same, do not put it into the array.

Comment: Hey! Trying this out right now. Thanks for the help!